# Can't Figure Out How to Fix CSS Width

Tags: html, css, formatting

My website's navigation renders properly on all computers, but is truncated/wrapped on mobile devices (iOS).

The relevant CSS is:

```
.custom .menu {
margin-top: 1.25em;
margin-left: 288px;
width: 442px;
}

.custom .menu a {
font-size: 1.4em;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
}
```

The relevant HTML is:

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-19"><a href="http://rainleader.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://rainleader.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://rainleader.com/services/">Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://rainleader.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="http://rainleader.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Here's how it should look (PC/Mac):

[image: Screenshot]

But on iOS, "Contact" is cut off the end and pushed below "Home". In other words, the menu ends at "Blog" and has a second row with only "Contact" in it.

If I increase the value of `width`, it extends the bottom border line at the end of the menu on PC/Mac without resolving the problem on iOS.

[image: Screenshot w/ Width Increased (PC/Mac)]

Noticed the extended bottom border line above, but it's still truncating/wrapping "Contact" on iOS.

What am I doing wrong? Or, how should I fix this?

[**Demo**](http://rainleader.com)

Comment: Could you share your HTML code for this menu?

Comment: You should see the width of you `#content` or `#content box`

Comment: Hi! You're correct, the line does extend to that value. However, I'm trying to limit it/force it to be shorter by targeting `.menu`. The menu should be centered under the logo, with no line extending beyond either edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set `width: 437px` to `.custom .menu` doesn't it fit nicely under the menu?

also, try using `.custom .menu { border: none; }` on the `<ul>`

Comment: That did it! I used `border-bottom: none;` because `border: none;` removed the left border on "Home."

Answer (score 1):

List Item isnt something you can force on a mobile browser. Maybe instead try using a image spacer? You are already trying to force width: 1017px; with your div container.

You can try overflow-x, but that may or may not work.

[**Reference**](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)

Comment: Hmm... Well I tried `overflow-x: auto;` and `overflow-x: hidden;` -- didn't change it. It seems like the magic width that solves the truncating issue is `width: 444px;`. However, set at that value, there's a little bit of the continuing bottom border line appearing on PC/Mac that is not apparent on mobile (even if you zoom in). Is this because pixels are not equal to each other on both devices? You can see this little line on the demo URL.